# Condition number for a complex square matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be non-singular. I have to prove that the condition number of A with the $p$-norm, $\kappa_p(A)$ ($1\leq p\leq\infty$), satisfies
$$\kappa_p(A) \geq \frac{\|A\|_p}{\|A-B\|_p},$$
for every singular matrix $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.

I don't know what to do with this and I'd appreciate any help someone could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{split}
\|A-B\|
&=
\max_{\|x\|=1}\|(A-B)x\|
\geq
\max_{\|x\|=1\\ Bx=0}\|(A-B)x\|
\\
&=
\max_{\|x\|=1\\ Bx=0}\|Ax\|
\geq
\min_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|
=
\frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}.
\end{split}
$$
Invert the inequality and multiply both sides by $\|A\|$. This holds for any operator norm (not just the $p$-norms).

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful!